# two basic questions about Bayesian learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I'm trying to understand Bayesian learning.  I've read some book and articles, and am still a bit confused.  I'd appreciate it if someone would clarify it, correct me, and/or give me some pointers.

1) My understanding is: Unlike the frequentist approach, where the learning algorithm takes a training set $\mathcal T$ and a hypothesis class $\mathcal H$ and outputs a hypothesis $h \in \mathcal H$, a Bayesian learning algorithm is additionally given a prior distribution $P(h)$ over $\mathcal H$ and outputs a posterior distribution $P(h\mid \mathcal T)$ over $\mathcal H$ according to Bayes Theorem

$$P(h\mid \mathcal T) =\frac{ P(\mathcal T\mid h)P(h)}{P(\mathcal T)} \propto P(\mathcal T\mid h)P(h)$$

Does this mean that the learning/training process in Bayesian learning is primarily in computing $P(\mathcal T\mid h)$ for each $h\in \mathcal H$, i.e. the so-called likelihood function?

2) How is the likelihood function $P(\mathcal T\mid h)$ usually determined?  A simple example, or a reference to one, would be much appreciated.  For example, can linear regression $Y=wX+b$ be learned with Bayesian approach?  If so, what would be a possible or typical way to compute $P(\mathcal T\mid h)$, where I suppose $h=(w, b)$ in this case?